# Find : $-\frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\cdots-\frac{1}{100}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Find following sum :
$$ -\frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\cdots-\frac{1}{100}$$

I think we can write $$\frac{-1}{101}+\sum_{n=1} ^{50} \left( - \frac{1}{2n} +\frac{1}{2n+1}\right)$$

Comment: The sum is sort of $\ln 2$, but missing a $1$ at the beginning, and a bunch of stuff at the end, which has total sum positive and less than $\frac{1}{101}$. So a not too terrible approximation is $\ln 2-1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT:**

We can write that $$-x+x^2-x^3+\ldots -x^{99}=(-x)\cdot \frac{1+x^{99}}{1+x}$$

Now integrate both sides from 0 to 1.

Can you see the magic?

Comment: I can't. What is the magic?

Comment: You're off by one power of $x$ in the numerator - consider what would happen for $x=-1$.

Comment: @πr8 Thanks. corrected.

Comment: @πr8 Should $x=-1$ matter? It goes from $0$ to $1$.

Comment: It doesn't matter particularly - it's just that in the previous form of what you'd written, the left side would be finite and the right side would have been $(1)\frac{2}{0}$, which wouldn't be. Just seemed like the quickest route to highlighting that they weren't equal. Could have equally considered asymptotic behaviour as $x\to\infty$

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an expression as a fraction, I imagine there's nothing particularly nice - WolframAlpha gives [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+n%3D2+to+100+of+%28-1%29%5E%28n%2B1%29%2Fn).

If you're looking for an approximation, you can spot it as a partial sum of $\ln(2)$, albeit missing the initial 1, so it ought to be close to $\ln(2)-1$

If you're looking for a neat expression of a different form, you can make use of the identity $\frac{1}{n}=\int_0^1 x^{n-1}dx$, and see that:

$$-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}\pm...-\frac{1}{100}=\int_0^1(-x+x^2-x^3\pm...-x^{99})dx$$

Then, we employ the formula for a finite geometric series and see that our sum is equal to:

$$\int_0^1(-x\frac{1+x^{99}}{1+x})dx$$

which is arguably nice.